# Synapse Pipeline Error: The column name is invalid

Tags: azure-synapse, azure-data-factory

I'm running a Synapse Pipeline which is moving data from SQL Server into Parquet files, but I'm getting an unusual error message. The error implies I have invalid characters in my column names, which I do not.

```
{
    "errorCode": "2200",
    "message": "ErrorCode=ParquetInvalidColumnName,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=The column name is invalid. Column name cannot contain these character:[,;{}()\\n\\t=],Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common,'",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Copy SQL data to Parquet",
    "details": []
}
```

Here are the column names:

[image]

As you can see there are no invalid characters.

What is causing this error?

Comment: Can you screenshot the column mapping on the copy activity? You might try clearing the mapping if you just want to use the same column names and types as the SQL table.

Answer (score 0):

Parquet format does not allow any white spaces or special characters in the column names. Make sure you do not have any trailing or leading spaces in the column names.

I have reproed with your column names and was able to load data from SQL server to the parquet file successfully.

Source:

[image]

Sink:

[image]

Mapping:

[image]

Sink data preview after loading successfully:

[image]